# Reflections in the 18th century

Tags: reference-request, mathematicians, group-theory

It is well known that the theory of reflections  was considerably developed during the 19th century with the development of group theory (e.g. Klein) and the theory of transformations. However, I'm interested to know who were the mathematicians that dealt with reflections during the 18th century and the beginning of the 19th century. A colleague of mine mentioned that several mathematicians looked on reflections in terms of foldings, in order to see if curves intersect themselves while being reflected; However, I didn't manage to find any sources for that.

Hence, any reference would be appreciated!

Comment: I got a huge number of hits for simultaneously googling ["optics" and "reflection"](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1700%2Ccd_max%3A1800&tbm=bks&q=optics+reflection&oq=optics+reflection) in google-books with the search restricted items between 1700 and 1800, but maybe you're looking for something different?

Comment: That certainly helps! but can one find "pure" mathematical reference to reflections? or that during that time, mechanics, optics and mathematics were pretty much combined together? thanks.

Comment: I think it was pretty much combined together. In the past few weeks I've been looking at the (very) old Tripos problems and problems from The Ladies' Diary (all this stuff is freely available on the internet by the way), and it seems that half -- maybe more than half -- of the problems are what we'd call physics problems today. You can find much (but not all) of this stuff collected together [here](http://web.mit.edu/redingtn/www/netadv/SPproblems.html), if you're interested.